# Pompt if no input entered

Tags: variables, powershell, input

If I just press enter without entering any variable.. it will spit out errors. What can I add to make it just repompt again?

```
 mode con: cols=35 lines=5
while (1) {
    $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
    if ($tag1 -eq "Q") {
        break;
    }

    mode con: cols=80 lines=46

    cls

    sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;

    cls

    start-sleep -seconds 2

    cls

    $OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}} -AutoSize;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="System Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} -AutoSize;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}} -AutoSize;

    "`n"

    "Current Date & Time: $(Get-Date -Format G)";

    "`n"

    Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1 | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.username}} -Autosize;

    Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | format-table EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of different ways:

```
$tag1 = $null
while (-not $tag1 ) {
    $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
    if ($tag1 -eq "Q") {
        return;
    }
}

mode con: cols=80 lines=46

cls

sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;

cls

start-sleep -seconds 2

cls

$OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}} -AutoSize;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="System Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} -AutoSize;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}} -AutoSize;

"`n"

"Current Date & Time: $(Get-Date -Format G)";

"`n"

Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1 | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.username}} -Autosize;

Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | format-table EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize;
```

Or:

```
$GetTag = {
 Switch (Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit')
  {
    'Q' {Return}
    ''  {.$GetTag}
    default {$_}
  }
}

 $tag = &$GetTag
```

Comment: I replaced lines 2-6 with both examples you have and I got Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.

Comment: I didn't include all of your other code as part of the example.  You have all your conde inside that While() loop, so you're ending up with an extra } at the end.

Comment: Okay that worked - but I still get the problem..If I am sitting at the prompt to enter a variable to use and I just hit 'Enter' ..like I forgot to type it in..it will still spit out lots of errors when I want it to just keep asking for the variable or Q to quit.

Comment: Take the rest of the code out of the loop, so you don't try to run it unti you have a good value for $Tags1.

Comment: For your first example listed, where should I paste the rest of the script?

Comment: I modifed the code to use Return instead of Break, and pasted the rest of your code into the first example.

Comment: When I ran your updated one, it worked, but then it closed right when it was completed and I want it to start from the beginning again like I had before.

Comment: Put it inside another loop, and change the "Q' action to "Exit"

Comment: Sorry I'm new to powershell :( can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the variable and then loop until it is set.

```
$tag1 = ""
while (-not ($tag1)) {
  $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
}
```

Comment: I still get the error. I wanted to just have the prompt keep asking for input instead of continuing the script if nothing is entered.